# My fav Segfault!! why?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

why this,causes a segfault??

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


 struct node 
  {
      double d;
      int *array;
      char c;
  };



  void allocator(struct node *ptr)
  {
      int *tmp;
      tmp = (int*)realloc(ptr, 10);
      if(!tmp)
      {
        ptr->array=tmp;
        ptr->array[0] = 23;
      }
  }


  int
   main()
   {
      struct node *ptr = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
      ptr->c = 'y';
      allocator(ptr);

      printf(" %c\n", ptr->c);      
      printf(" %d\n", ptr->array[0]);
      return 0;
   }
```

i got an impression as if the realloc() in the allocator function allocates memory which also maps to the memory allocated by malloc() in the main..

but how does this could happen?? Doesn't the memory manager(i guess the lib(stdlib) here) keeps track of free and allocated spaces in a process??

Comment: If realloc moves the pointer, ie, "tmp" in allocator is different than "ptr", then in the calling function (main) ptr is no longer a valid pointer. You would need to return the changed pointer back out to main.

Comment: yeah true...but i was try to realloc the int pointer array instead of the struct node itself.... i.e.   realloc(ptr->darray, 10)  struggling for an hr or so in it....could only found this silly mistake solved it after receiving comments here thanks anyways

Answer (score 6):

You're allocating space enough for a `struct node` then `realloc`ating it to 10 bytes, then accessing the member `c` which, due to the structure of `node`, is probably past the 10th byte. This causes a segfault.

Also, if whoever's business it is to decide decides that it needs to move the memory block, `realloc` returns a pointer to the new location but the pointer back in `main` still points to the old block which has been reclaimed. This could also cause a segfault.

**Also**, in this code:

```
int *tmp;
tmp = (int*)realloc(ptr, 10);
if(!tmp)
{
  ptr->array=tmp;
  ptr->array[0] = 23;
}
```

if `!tmp`, you're accessing a `NULL` pointer because you're assigning `tmp` to `ptr->array` then accessing the 0th element. This could also cause a segfault.

There are many problems in your code. You may need to rewrite much of it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this is the attempt to access an unallocated pointer, which happens in main:

printf(" %d\n", ptr->array[0]);

Your allocation function assigns space for ptr, which is a structure, but not for the array within that structure. Possibly this is not what you intended to do (comment your code!).